# Angular CLI build prod javascript/css links don't work

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

I'm using the Angular CLI to compile my Angular app down to JS and CSS files. I'm using `ng build --environment prod` to compile.

When looking at the `index.html` file in the `dist` folder, I see that the JS and CSS files are linked properly like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

But then when I open the `index.html` file, Safari complains that these files aren't found. But when I edited the HTML file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Users/me/proj/dist/script.js"></script>
```

Everything works... How can I fix this? Here's how the `dist` folder looks like, roughly.

```
dist
  |--------- index.html
  |--------- styles.css
  |--------- script.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dist` folder is meant to be deployed to a production server ... not run directly from your system.

As part of the ng build --prod you can specify the base URL to use for your production server. That defines where it will find the files.

```
ng build --prod --base-href myProductionServerFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem like this.

ng build --prod --base-href /dist